# How can I 'hide' icons away to a different panel?

Tags: panel, mate, ubuntu-mate

I'm building up a lot of notification icons. On windows, there's an extra panel where the 'hidden' icons are so is there a similar solution for this on MATE? (I don't want to remove the icons, but simply hide them somewhere. So I just need a convenient way to do this)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two possible ways:

### Using Drawer applet

1. Right click on the panel and select **Add to Panel...**
2. Select **Drawer** from the list of applets
3. Right click on the **Drawer** icon and select **Add to Drawer...**
4. Select **Indicator Applet Complete**, **Notification Area** etc. from the list

Now you'll see all those icons only after clicking on the **Drawer** icon.

### Adding an extra panel

1. Right click on the panel and select **New Panel**
2. Right click on the new panel and select **Add to Panel...**
3. Select **Indicator Applet Complete**, **Notification Area** etc. from the list
4. Right click on the new panel and select **Properties**
5. Select **Orientation** *(position)* as you like and mark the checkbox next to **Autohide**

Now the new panel with all those icons will only show up when you drag the mouse pointer to the correct edge of the screen.

Comment: I've done the same now. By the way **Using Drawer applet** doesn't work, adding Notification Area doesn't do anything.  I'm wondering if its because **Drawers** opens vertically.

Comment: No @Phil, I guess that's not the reason. You can probably have only one instance of **Notification Area** running in panel. So you have to first remove the **Notification Area** applet from the panel and then add it to **Drawer**. Hope this solves the issue. **Notification Area** works fine inside **Drawer** for me.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the "arrow" that is overlaid atop the drawer icon? [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328198/mate-hide-arrow-on-panel-drawer-icons) from four years ago asks similar, but has no answers.